# Converting scroll bar coordinates to mouse coordinates

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make a scroll bar and at the moment, the scroll works by changing the coordinates when blitting (as opposed to changing the actual rect coordinates). This means that rect collisions for buttons do not work when they are moved. I am attempting to combat this by calculating the percentage that the scroll bar has scrolled, converting that to some multiplier or screen coordinate, and then getting the mouse position.

Some notes:
Self.bar is the actual slider handle (the small thing you use to scroll)
Self.rect is the entire slider, and its height is equal to screen height
Self.total_h is the total height that the scroll bar needs to scroll, for example if it needed to scroll to 2x the screen height then total_h would equal screen_height * 2.

Some code I have tried so far:

```
# Calculate the distance between the top of the handle and the top of the overall bar and divide by the handle height 
# (shortened from ((self.bar.rect.top - self.rect.top) / self.rect.h) * (self.rect.h / self.bar.rect.h) which makes more intuitive sense.
self.scroll_percent = ((self.bar.rect.top - self.rect.top) / self.bar.rect.h)
# These all do not work:
# pos_y = pg.mouse.get_pos()[1] * self.scroll_percent
# pos_y = pg.mouse.get_pos()[1] * (self.total_h / self.scroll_percent)
# pos_y = (self.total_h / self.scroll_percent) * pg.mouse.get_pos()[1]
# etc
```

The logic just doesn't make sense to me, and I've got no idea how to do this. To clarify, my goal is to allow the user to scroll the screen using a scroll bar, and depending on the scroll bar's position, we change the mouse pos accordingly.

Comment: I have no idea how this code works. Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for a more theoretical solution to this problem, rather than knowing the actual syntax. Something like the different steps involved in transforming a scroll bar to a screen

Comment: theoretical solution? You already have `percent` for `scrollbar` and now you have to write the same for  mouse `percent = (mouse_current - top) / height` and convert it to `percent * height = (mouse_current - top)` and next to `mouse_current = top + (percent * height)`. It's pure math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand why you bother with some percentage ? If I understood correctly you are only scrolling up and down so the only thing you need to know is the y offset, which is 0 when the scroll bar is at the top and then it is just the y value at which you are blitting your surface. So simply remove the y offset to your mouse y when you check for collision.
Maybe I missed something ?

If I understood corretly, here is an simple example of what to do :
(I didn't recreate the scroll bar since you said you've got this part working. I just made the surface go up automatically. I'm sure you will figure out a way to integrate this solution to your own code)

```
# General import
import pygame as pg
import sys

# Init
pg.init()

# Display
screen = pg.display.set_mode((500, 500))
FPS = 30
clock = pg.time.Clock()

# Surface declaration
drawing_surface = pg.Surface((screen.get_width(), screen.get_height() * 2))
drawing_surface.fill((255,0,0))
drawing_surface_y = 0

# Button
test_btn = pg.Rect(20, 400, 100, 40)

# Main functions
def update():
    global drawing_surface_y
    drawing_surface_y -= 1

def draw():
    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    # Render the button
    pg.draw.rect(drawing_surface, (0,0,255), test_btn)

    # Blit the drawing surface
    screen.blit(drawing_surface, (0, drawing_surface_y))

def handle_input():
    for evt in pg.event.get():
        if evt.type == pg.QUIT:
            exit()
        if evt.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if evt.button == 1:
                on_click()

def on_click():
    mx, my = pg.mouse.get_pos()
    if test_btn.collidepoint(mx, my - drawing_surface_y):
        print("Test button has been clicked")

def exit():
    pg.quit()
    sys.exit()

# Other functions

# Main loop
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        handle_input()
        update()
        draw()
        pg.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)
```

Test this code and let me know if it answers your question !

Comment: Yes, I was overcomplicating it previously. It works now by just calculating a y_offset as you stated. I'm not sure why I was using percentages previously, but this is a very simple solution. Thanks.

Comment: No problems, glad to help and this my first answer that gets accepted so I'm happy :) ! I feel you, sometimes we can over complicate problems without realizing. This often a sign you've been staring at your code editor for too long. When I get stuck on a problem I usually take out a pen and paper and use sketches and hand writing to come up with a solution. Getting away from the computer for a little bit really helps. Of course you can also just take a break and when you'll get back to it, you'll find new solutions or notice a flaw in your previous resoning.